# How to remove data based on the timestamp

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
head(data1)
# A tibble: 6 × 10
  Date       Time     Axis1 Axis2 Axis3    VM Standing Stepping Cycling
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2022-03-17 11:29:00     0     0     0     0        0        0       0
2 2022-03-17 11:29:00     0     0     0     0        0        0       0
3 2022-03-17 11:29:00     0     0     0     0        0        0       0
4 2022-03-17 11:29:00     0     0     0     0        0        0       0
5 2022-03-17 11:29:00     0     0     0     0        0        0       0
6 2022-03-17 11:29:00     0     0     0     0        0        0       0
# … with 1 more variable: New_Sitting <dbl>
```

It has a data point every second all day, every day for a week. Is it possible to remove the data points outside of the workday? (Say only keep the data between 7am-5pm of the weekdays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `weekdays()` and `data.table::between()`.

```
res <- dat[!weekdays(dat$time) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday") &
  data.table::between(as.integer(gsub('\\D', '', substring(dat$time, 12))), 7e4, 17e4), ]
```

### Gives

```
names(table(substr(res$time, 12, 13)))
# [1] "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17"

names(table(weekdays(res$time)))
# [1] "Friday"    "Monday"    "Thursday"  "Tuesday"  
# [5] "Wednesday"
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- data.frame(time=seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct('2022-01-01'), as.POSIXct('2022-01-14'), 'hour'))
dat$X <- rnorm(nrow(dat))
```

Comment: It returns```Error in UseMethod("weekdays") : 
no applicable method for 'weekdays' applied to an object of class "character"```

Comment: You need an appropriate `time` variable in `"POSIXct"` format. Do `transform(dat, time=as.POSIXct(Reduce(paste, dat[c('Date', 'Time')])))` beforehand, this pastes together your separate date and time columns and converts to `"POSIXct"` .

Comment: ```transform(data1, Time=as.POSIXct(Reduce(paste, data1[c('Date', 'Time')])))
res <- data1[!weekdays(data1$Time) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday") &
  data.table::between(as.integer(gsub('\\D', '', substring(data1$Time, 12))), 7e4, 17e4), ]``` still returns ```Error in UseMethod("weekdays") : 
no applicable method for 'weekdays' applied to an object of class "character"```

Comment: @RichardMichaudLangis You need it to assign back to your data of course, `data1 <- transform(data1, ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:
Note that we first create a datetime object, then we filter whereby the weekday is between 1:5, and the time is between 07(7am) and 17(5pm)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date_time = ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time)))%>%
  filter(format(date_time, "%u")%in%1:5, 
         date_time>=ymd_h(paste(Date, "07")),
         date_time <= ymd_h(paste(Date, "17"))) %>%
  select(-date_time)
```

Comment: This returns `Error in filter(): ! Problem while computing ..2 = between(...). Caused by error in between(): ! left must be length 1`

Comment: Would it be possible to add something to bring back the data frame headers to normal after? Since I have code that follows that does not work because of this mutate

Comment: @AndreaM just add `select(-date_time)` after the filter

Comment: That did not remove any data

Comment: @AndreaM in this example  all the data meet the conditions